# Get the list of devices with their hostnames and ip addresses on LAN in iOS swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, ip, lan, hostname

I am trying to get the details of connected devices on Local Area Network like [Fing](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107) or [iNet](https://apps.apple.com/il/app/inet-network-scanner/id340793353). I have tried some libraries: [MMLanScan](https://github.com/mavris/MMLanScan) or [LAN-Scan](https://github.com/mongizaidi/LAN-Scan) and got IP addresses but couldn't get the hostnames. Please share if anyone has gone through this before.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am providing here answer to this question though it is sort of late response,
you may get those information via this repository
[LAN-Scanner github](https://github.com/jaszczurtd/LAN-Scanner)